# Visualforce Error URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

There is one fields in campaign object name Expected Response (%) is not decoded by URL. I am using javascript on VF page to encode but some how it is not able to decode "(%)" .Can anyone faced the same issue ? if yes , Please help me .

Thanks,  Prashant

Comment: I am waiting for reply frnds ..please help..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. Are you passing parameters to fields via url, similar to http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html?

`Expected Response` is a standard field on [Campaign object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_campaign.htm).

Use some HTML inspector to view the "name" attribute for the field, you should get `cpn11`.

[image: Screenshot of relevant part of the form + Chrome HTML inspector]

So your URL hack should look similar to `https://(instance).salesforce.com/701/e?cpn11=12.34`